# How to use SUM in pivot table(CAST cannot be used in aggregate function)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

I am using the following pivot query:

```
    select UserId_Fk,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday
      from CheckInCheckOut

    PIVOT
    (

     SUM(CAST(CountHours as decimal(18,2))) 
     FOR Day
     IN([Sunday],[Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday])

    )
   as PivotTable

   Table[CheckInCheckOut]     

 CheckInCheckOutId  int 
    UserId_Fk       int 
  CountHours    nvarchar(50)    
         Day    nvarchar(50)
```

There is something wrong how I am using SUM here. I tried

```
   select SUM(CAST(CountHours as decimal(18,2))) from CheckInCheckOut
```

which gives me the correct result, but the same I am not able to use in Pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try cast your data before make a pivot query

```
  select UserId_Fk,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday
      from    (Select UserId_Fk,CAST(CountHours as decimal(18,2))as CountHours,[Day]
   from CheckInCheckOut) as convertedtable

    PIVOT
    (

     SUM(CountHours) 
     FOR Day
     IN([Sunday],[Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday])

    )
   as PivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't use sql-server/pivot this is only a guess, but should it not be a group by clause in there? I.e.

```
...
as PivotTable
group by UserId_Fk, ...
```